# Trouble connecting a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I'm after getting some help to make a [bluetooth](/questions/tagged/bluetooth) keyboard work, I can't figure out how to get it to connect and stay connected so it will work to allow me to enter my password when switching the PC on. The bluetooth [mouse](/questions/tagged/mouse) works just fine.

`user@pc:~$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 00:07:61:50:C8:24 BamBam2 [default]
[NEW] Device 00:07:61:4C:C8:3D Dell BT Mouse
[NEW] Device 00:07:61:4D:8A:81 Dell BT Keyboard
Agent registered
[Dell BT Mouse]# info 00:07:61:4D:8A:81
Device 00:07:61:4D:8A:81 (public)
    Name: Dell BT Keyboard
    Alias: Dell BT Keyboard
    Class: 0x00002540
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v046DpB308d7312
[Dell BT Mouse]# connect 00:07:61:4D:8A:81
Attempting to connect to 00:07:61:4D:8A:81
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[Dell BT Mouse]#`

I sometimes get a box that pops up that asks me to input a PIN. I don't know what the PIN is and the bluetooth [keyboard](/questions/tagged/keyboard) won't type anything anyway. Sometimes it randomly connects, not sure why, but it loses the connection if I reboot. I have looked at the related questions but they have not helped.
Thanks.

Comment: **You are right**. I understand the problem you are facing, its quite frustrating I may add. **Editing** is a process of making question and answers better.  Your words do describe your problem. Sometimes we edit post to correct grammar, correct spellings, improve formatting, adding more information, removing information, adding tags, removing tags, inserting in-line tags etc. **Edits** are done to make the site clean and better. It is not some kind of English lesson. **About the technical help**, yes that's kind of what this website is for. Please wait for someone to come with an answer.

Comment: I do feel sorry for the misunderstanding. You got me wrong. I do appreciate and welcome you here to the community.

Comment: Thank you @Hasan, I appreciate your kind response.

Comment: About your problem, there's some bug in the latest release. The whole [tag:bluetooth] thing is kind of messed up right now. See it [here](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-bluetooth/issues/67).

Comment: Try entering 0000 as a PIN

Comment: I' ve tried that, but I cant use the bluetooth keyboard - not sure if it counts typing 0000 from the wired keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by checking turning on the keyboard and setting it to pairing mode. Then you should select it in the available devices on the OS, click pair button, wait for a prompt to enter the key, enter 0000, and repeat this process a few times taking 1 to 2 seconds before inputting 0000. After this, the system should recognize and use the Bluetooth keyboard.